# How to create two admin view and separating the model between 2 admin views by using rails_admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, administration, admin-interface

I want to create two admin views by using rails_admin gem. I created one admin and i specify the `path( mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin' in routes.rb)`.

Similarly I specified another `path (mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/superadmin', :as => 'superadmin' )`.

Now I am getting the same views for both superadmin and admin view. I used devise and cancan for authentication.

But I want to seperate the model in 2 views. I don't know where to make changes. 
In `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` I included some models but it is reflected in both admin views.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You cant achieve that using `rails_admin`. I've tried couple of months ago and found its not made for that.

Currently I am using rails_admin for SuperAdmin as its required less customization.

And

I am using active_admin for normal administration.

Answer (score 0):

Rails admin lets you customize stuff by user but you'll have to do a tedious configuration for all your models. If you want super fine grained customization. For example

```
edit do
  field :avatar do
    visible do
      bindings[:view]._current_user.id
    end
  end
end
```

You can always use cancancan and customize your can read permissions depending on the type of user, rails_admin will honor them.